# Outputting script execution time on Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

is there a way to output the execution time on the screen?
For example, in my Rails application if I call a controller from the index controller, I'd like to have the time it took to query the data displayed on the bottom of the page.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Railscasts episode on Rack](http://railscasts.com/episodes/151-rack-middleware) (ASCII version [here](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/151-rack-middleware)) shows how to calculate the time elapsed, but it shows it as an HTML comment at the top of the response body.

My approach would then be to put a certain token in my application layout (for example, `<!-- REQUEST TIME -->`) and then perform a gsub over the response body replacing that string with the request time, calculated as in the previous links.